# Can't open a ticket for merging accounts; Error occurs even though all fields are included

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts, contact

I tried to follow the instruction in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) but I can't open a ticket for merging accounts. I get the following error:

[image: error messages]

[image: HTTP request for clicking submit button]

> We can't merge until we have links to both profiles; please add the missing URL and try again

Of course, I have filled all the required information before clicking the "Submit" button, including the field that it indicates is missing.

I can see the second profile URL I entered in the web request made on submission, but I still get an error back.

What should I do?

Comment: If you don't have the link to your second account and instead need help finding that account, then it sounds like you should open up a separate ticket for that first (perhaps under "Other"), since a merge can't happen between two account unless you know which accounts should be merged.

Comment: I can log in to both accounts, so I have no problems for providing account details. I'm wondering if the support ticket system is broken.

Comment: Also, please tell me if this place is not the right place to ask for help. Since I have a problem opening a ticket, and Stackoverflow itself doesn't have a support center, I have no idea where I should ask for help.

Comment: Did you try to fill "Your other profile link" and click "I'm not a robot" box before submit?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ 
> Of course, I have filled all the required information before clicking the "Submit" button.

Comment: Then much better to upload an updated image to your question. Since the current one may introduce misunderstanding and leads to downvotes.

Comment: However, when I try to fill out the form one more time, no error message is displayed. Therefore, posting a form with values entered does not help at all in explaining the problem. It's absurd that posting an error message of the current state could be considered an idiot who doesn't understand StackExchange's rules. This question is not for discussion, but to get help with the broken functionality of the ticket open system.

Comment: My plausible guess is as follows: When I click the "Submit" button, javascript tries to find the wrong element to submit, calls API with "Your other profile link" field empty, and the server returns an error, finally the error is displayed.

Comment: Okay, the HTTP request contains `otherProfileLink` field with a valid value, but it returns 200 with an error message displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: Apologies @ByoungchanLee, I misunderstood that you had filled out the second link field but that it cleared on submission, that's very clearly not how that's supposed to work!

Comment: There's definitely a chance the downvotes are from folks who interpreted the question like I did at first, where I saw your screenshot with the apparently missing info and missed where you said you included all fields. Regardless, you can probably reach out using a different form option (e.g. Other) if this one isn't working and you don't want to wait for a fix in the meantime.

Comment: I didn't think that reporting that the ticket system wasn't working would get me down-voted by so many people. This post is not attacking StackExchange leadership, debating about ChatGPT usage, or inciting a strike. I just wanted to know if the ticket system was working or not.

Comment: I wrote "Of course, I have filled all the required information before clicking the \"Submit\" button" in the body because I thought that Screenshots may cause others to think that I forgot the required form. What if I didn't upload the image of Chrome's Developer Console? I'm glad I knew how to use that feature, but if I didn't, this post would have gotten more downvotes.

Anyway, I opened a ticket with 'others type' and added this page as a link.

Comment: I think others were perceiving that you were somehow thinking that you thought that the empty field wasn't required and trying to submit anyway. Phrasing it as "I entered my other account but the field kept getting cleared every time I submitted" (or the actual behavior you were facing) would have went a much longer way.

Comment: I think it's much better to contact support for this issue using the "Other" option.

Comment: On Stack Overflow Meta: [I need help to merge two profiles I have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426064). On MathOverflow Meta: [Account merging](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5749).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you so much for reporting this issue! This was happening as a result of a refactor that changed every place where we reference the 'OtherProfileLink' except for one that continued to reference the 'OtherProfileUrl'. This is now fixed, please let me know if you're still having issues with submitting the merge request.